# Get the dimensions(sizes) of a 3d model with js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, augmented-reality

I actually work on AR project with three.js and i handle some 3d models, but I have some problem with the sizes of the models. Because I want them to all have the same size, so I needed to set the same dimensions to all models. I first tried to solve this by using boundingbox and boundingsphere but it doesn't work.

So how can I get the sizes and how can I set the sizes ?

Comment: You can [scale](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Object3D.scale) your object, if you know its size and the desired size.

Comment: You're right ! Thanks :) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var size = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( yourObject ).getSize(new THREE.Vector3())`

Comment: Thanks, with this code i can get the size but how can i set the size ? Because the size of my 3d model sin't affect by these changes :/

Comment: You'll have to take that size.. find the max of .x, .y, .z.. then do yourObject.scale.multiplyScalar(desired size / the max) .. that should scale your model to be your desired size. Does that make sense? (multiplyScalar just means multiply x,y,z by some number)

Comment: How to find the max ?

Comment: Math.max(Math.abs(size.x),Math.abs(size.y),Math.abs(size.z))

Answer (score 1):

I need somethig else, because the code of manthrax is interesting but have some limits.. for exemple with this code:

```
andy.scale.set(0.011, 0.011, 0.011);
                                andy.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
                                andy.position.set(0,0,0);
                                var size = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(andy).getSize(new THREE.Vector3())
                                console.log(size);

                                function moy(vect){
                                    return ((vect.x+vect.y+vect.z)/3);;
                                }

                                console.log(moy(size));

                                andy.scale.set(0.030, 0.030, 0.030);
                                console.log(moy(size));
```

If i want to change the value of "size" how can i do that ?

PS: andy is my 3d model

I solve it, i create my own box3:

```
                        andy.scale.set(0.011, 0.011, 0.011);
                        andy.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
                        andy.position.set(0,0,0);
                        var box3d = new THREE.Box3();
                        var size = box3d.setFromObject(andy).getSize(new THREE.Vector3())
                        console.log(size);

                        function moy(vect){
                            return ((vect.x+vect.y+vect.z)/3);;
                        }

                        console.log(moy(size));

                        andy.scale.set(0.030, 0.030, 0.030);
                        box3d.setFromObject(andy).getSize(size);
                        console.log(moy(size));
```